# Select the last of type before another element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to add a bottom margin to the last paragraphs. It should be selected if there are other element types after the paragraph. For visual purpose I will use red backgrounds in my example. I would like the `<p>` before the second `<h2>` to be also red. I can't see how to select this element. `:nth-child()` will not work, as the number of elements could vary. Thank you!

```css
p:last-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>This should not be red</p>
<p>This should be red</p>
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>This should not be red</p>
<p>This should be red</p>
```

Comment: You can not select an element based on what might or might not come after it. You could select `h2` elements that come after a `p` though (adjacent sibling combinator), and apply a margin-top to those instead.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I think that could work for my use case. I will look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

you can give them a shared class and control this class like this example

```css
 .p_red {
     background-color : red;
    }
```

```html
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>This should not be red</p>
    <p class = "p_red">This should be red</p>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>This should not be red</p>
    <p class= "p_red">This should be red</p>
```